# How to view RAM utilistion of a Google Cloud VM instance?

Tags: memory, charts, google-cloud-platform, utilization

I'm using Google Cloud VM instances but I can't find the RAM Utilisation chart.

When accessing through https://console.cloud.google.com, go to Hamburger Menu >> Compute Engine >> VM instances, click on one instance; there is one select box on top-left area with the following options:

- CPU utilization
- Disk bytes
- Disk operations
- Network bytes
- Network packets

But no **RAM utilization** option, where can I find this chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Install the Stackdriver Agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) on your instance. It will log RAM, along with a number of additional metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud has no such RAM utilisation chart, and also Stackdriver doesn't have.

I had to install NetData instead:
http://my-netdata.io